# Is it possible to use isUtilityPoppedOut() in LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components, utility-bar

This function is exactly what I need to control certain utility behaviors that should only occur when the utility is popped out. However this seems to be written for Aura. Is it possible to do this in LWC? And if so, how?

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_lightning_isUtilityPoppedOut.htm

Comment: You could host your lwc component in a parent aura component that contains the utility bar functinality... not a great solution, but it's the best I can think of

Comment: Yeah, shoot. Probably wouldn't be worth it. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by looking for the presence of "0.windowed=true" in the window.location.href property. There is also "popout/utility" in the path as well. Not sure which will be more future-proof but I went with the windowed param.

https://abc.lightning.force.com/lightning/popout/utility?0.windowed=true